# Why is my circuit in parallel with a voltage regulator overheating?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, voltage-regulator, raspberry-pi, amperage

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmc700.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm currently working on a project where we use a Raspberry Pi to print receipts via a receipt printer. I would like to use the same power supply for the Pi and receipt printer so we don't need to worry about staff at the restaurants that will be using this accidentally unplugging one component and not knowing about it. I tried to solder two wires onto the power supply input (from an AC to DC converter 24V, 2.5A out) and then step down the voltage through a voltage regulator. With this method I ended up burning the microcontroller in the receipt printer seemingly when I connected it to the Pi's USB ports. I have a few ideas why this might have happened but I'm not sure, could someone point me in the right direction?

Possible Problems
-The voltage regulator is drawing more then 24V which would force the receipt printer to the same voltage
-The voltage regular draws too many amps and few are left for the receipt printer
-An issue with shared grounds between the pi and printer

More info on the printer (I don't think the datasheet has been released)
http://hoinprinter.com/en/download
LM2596 datasheet https://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-LM2596-DC-DC-adjustable-power-step-down-module-NEW-GOOD-QUALITY-M13-/351493700220?_trksid=p2385738.m2548.l4275
LM2596 implementation board https://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-LM2596-DC-DC-adjustable-power-step-down-module-NEW-GOOD-QUALITY-M13-/351493700220?_trksid=p2385738.m2548.l4275

This is an image of where I soldered the voltage regulator leads to the board. (These wires go to IN the the above schematic)
[image]

Printer Boards[image]

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for the receipt printer?

Comment: I don't think the company gives that out. These documents are as close as I've gotten: http://hoinprinter.com/en/download

Comment: Does the "voltage regulator" module (datasheet plz) have an isolated output? If so, how are you grounding it to the 24V supply?

Comment: After looking it up the correct name is a step down regulator the data sheet can be found at: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/LM2596-D.PDF I'm using a board from eBay with the chip pre-implemented on it https://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-LM2596-DC-DC-adjustable-power-step-down-module-NEW-GOOD-QUALITY-M13-/351493700220?_trksid=p2385738.m2548.l4275 . I am not doing anything special to ground it. I had assumed connected the negative pin on the out of the regulator chip would ground it.

Comment: Did you measure the output voltage from the regulator? And also does the Pi still work?

Comment: There are no issues with the Pi. I measured the output from the regulator while attached to the voltage regulator and it was about 27V. This was when the printer was powered off and the USB was not connected.

Comment: Do you mean the 5V output from LM2596 read 27V? That would be a tough case...

Comment: No, there was 27V going into the input of the LM2596, I set the variable resistor on the board with the LM2596 so that the output read 5V. That test was completed when there was nothing drawing power from the LM2596 so it may have gone higher with load.

Comment: This is most likely a grounding problem.  The printer's circuit board looks like it has a switching power converter on it.  So, both the Pi and the printer power up just fine... and then when you connect the USB cable, the Pi's GND pin shorts the printer's switching power supply.

Comment: @RubberStamp Is there anyway I can get around that other than using separate power supplies for both devices? The printer works in that scenario but I would like to use the same supply is possible.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way around the problem.  You could change out the 5V linear converter for a switching one.  However, the cost and maintenance of such a setup is likely much more trouble than it's worth.... However, it also looks like there's more than one USB port on the printer... but I can't see the connector from the picture.  If there's another USB port, you might be able to power the Pi from the 2nd port... but be sure to use a power only cable (sans data lines), and that may overload the printer's switching supply.

Comment: @RubberStamp Would something like this work instead of the switch regulator? https://www.ebay.com/itm/Converter-Regulator-24V-Step-Down-to-5V-5A-25W-Switch-Power-DC-DC-Voltage/112545050435?epid=1240435221&hash=item1a34352f43:g:2pgAAOSwmo5ZpjMh

Comment: The important thing is the isolation transformer.  I can't tell from the description if that product is a switching converter which would have the necessary isolation.  Something like this may work: [DLW05B-05](https://www.jameco.com/z/DLW05B-05-MEAN-WELL-5W-Regulated-Dual-Output-DC-DC-Converter-5-Volts-0-5-Amps-18-36VDC_2100603.html)

Comment: @Trent, do you have a schematic diagram for the LM2596 DC/DC converter board (not the IC, but the PCB)? You want to ensure that the PCB's IN- and OUT- terminals are shorted together, that there are no components between those two terminals on the PCB.

Answer (score 1):

It happened when you plugged in the USB? That seems to suggest it created a short to me. You can probably test that with everything powered down. Plug everything together without the DC input and check with your multi-meter (although, you probably need to test with a board that isn't burnt out).

In that case you need to swap out that buck converter board for an isolated one. Really you should be isolating the Pi from the other board any way. Having them on a common circuit and then making another connection between them (USB) strikes me as pretty risky, especially without having any idea how the printer circuit is designed.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the printer manual and translating it http://hoinprinter.com/en/download , **I do not see any supply spec near 27V.**  How did you determine this or was this a supply that came with the printer?

- HOP-E58 58MM

  - Power Adapter Input: AC 110V / 220V, 50 ~ 60Hz
  - power supply Output: DC 12V / 2A
  - Cash box output DC 12V / 1A

Comment: I'm using the 80mm version of the product which required 24V (http://hoinprinter.com/en/products/show/Thermal-Receipt-Printer-2#p1). I also tested the power input with my multimeter and it is in the 24.X range when I measure it with no load.

Comment: You may have to insert a small series R to test and measure surge startup currents that may affect transient overvoltage.  Can you see any cause for Latchup? external voltage applied before DC in?

Comment: There is a chance voltage could be coming from the USB before the printer is powered on via its "ON" switch. Although this should be a fairly regular occurrence so I would assume its designers would have accounted for it.

Comment: Are there any R-Pi peripherals with different grounds?  Is there an earth ground anywhere?  YOu ought to measure the current thru a sense R on ground or V+ to each DC supply to diagnose the problem

Comment: There are no other peripherals. I will try to set up an R test on the board to see what I'm getting.